# How to create an issue via REST API in Jira Cloud?

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create issue using REST API in PHP. Here is my code. But

```
$headers = array(
'Accept' => 'application/json',
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
'Bearer' => $access_token //api token from https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html 
);

$body = <<<REQUESTBODY
{
    "fields": {
        "project":
                {
                    "key": "<PROJECT KEY>"
                },

        "issuetype": {"id": "<ISSUE ID>"},
        "subtask": "false",
    }
}
REQUESTBODY;

$response = Unirest\Request::post(
  'https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue',
  $headers,
  $body
);
```

But it returns

```
[issuetype] => The issue type selected is invalid.
                    [project] => Anonymous users do not have permission to create issues in this project. Please try logging in first.
```

Seems issue Id is not invalid as I got the issueType ID from "rest/api/latest/issuetype"

I have to set the permission somewhere. But I cant find where can I set the permissions. I am using the trial account of Jira Cloud. Is there any limitation on the trial account?

I see [X-AUSERNAME] => anonymous in my header. How can I set username?

Comment: Can you replace `"id":"<ISSUE ID>"` with `"name":"<ISSUE TYPE>"` and try? That will work!

Comment: If you aren't married to PHP you can use powershell's [JiraPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JiraPS) module. It has commands like New-JiraIssue that make it super simple.